# Donation for good answers with Flattr?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

What about the idea that users can set their flattr account inside their profile (if they have got one). If they set it, a flattr button could appear beside their answers, so free-handed members could make a financial donation to them after they gave good answer. Whereby it doesn't have to be flattr, maybe SO could make an own implementation.

Benefits:
Because users could earn real money, they are more motivated to give good answers. Now you only get badges or points for good answers, but if you could get real money too, maybe even more people make efforts to give answers.

Comment: Do we get money back when someone creates a bad answer?

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't understand. You don't have to donate. The idea is to donate AFTER a good answers was given.

Comment: I don't know. Currently stackoverflow and a lot of things here are working because people are here on a volunteer basis. This can be abused as someone giving you money and then wanting an answer for you. Or you will have people who answer like 90% of the newest questions because they want to do it full-time or sth. Then you need to meet a "quota". Just implementing a way for financial transaction can open some doors which people may not want to. 
You can always put your paypal or website with flattr or whatever in your profile if you want donations though.

Comment: @Hayt The idea is to NOT give money in the first place, but some1 can give it for free AFTER a good answer is given. Or maybe other people who found a solution in an old question could donate money too. As it already happens with upvotes.

Comment: Good question and answers are a donation itself.

Comment: @nikoshr Yes, the idea is the same. Ok, they already told their position. My Question is answered then.

Comment: _The idea is to NOT give money in the first place, but some1 can give it for free AFTER a good answer is given._ What then stops answerers from seeking out questions by people who have shown will to pay (or who disclose that will in the question)? Thats the problem with extrinsic motivations, if you place one, people will game it. a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Because users could earn real money, they are more motivated to give
>   good answers.

Thats an extrinsic motivation. The problem with that is that they aren't as strong as intrinsic motivations, like helping people or contributing to great QA, and they tend to replace and diminish intrinsic motivations.

A few words from one of the founders of this website on that:

> One big problem is that it replaces intrinsic motivation with
>   extrinsic motivation.
>
> Intrinsic motivation is your own, natural desire to do things well.
>   People usually start out with a lot of intrinsic motivation. They want
>   to do a good job. They want to help people understand that it’s in
>   their best interest to keep paying AOL $24 a month. They want to write
>   less-buggy code.
>
> Extrinsic motivation is a motivation that comes from outside, like
>   when you’re paid to achieve something specific. [(source)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/09.html)

The point behind this is that right now, barring some meaningless(*) internet points, the primary form of motivation for answerers to contribute is to solve people's problems, help each other and create a great and well curated source of knowledge.

If you bring money into the mix, you'll get a lot of people who will optimize for money, e.G answer in such a way to maximize their "income" from the site, leading to some *super* undesirable side effects that could be unrivaled in their potency and vileness (Like people cheap shotting each other when competing for donations, or dishonest answer practices, etc.).

We get these problems now, when our only extrinsic motivation factor is rep. Imagine how much more intense they'll get when we replace worthless internet points(*) with actual money.

We already had highly recieved [meta discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation) about how StackOverflow already has *too much* extrinsic motivation (fast rep) and I'm not sure anyone would argue that adding another, much much stronger source of that is going to go over well with our model.

**I know some people like reputation a lot, but it's by a long shot not as strong a factor as actual money would be.*

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks.